# How to change the Value of an R structure in Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a list of list of vector in R, a structure like this:

```
A=list();
for(i in 1:n){
  A[[i]]=list
  for(j in 1:m){
    A[[i]][[j]]=rep(0,m);
  }
}
```

and when I pass A into a Rcpp function,

```
RcppExport SEXP func(SEXO RA){
  Rcpp:: List A(RA)
  as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(as<Rcpp::List>(A(i))(j))(n)=2;
}
```

but the value of `A(i)(j)(n)` wont change and still remains 0, any body knows what is the problem?

Thanks 
I am not able to change the value of `A[[i]][[j]][[n]]`

Answer (score 1):

You posted first on the rcpp-devel list (which is a good idea).  I replied there.

You seem to have some basic misunderstanding about the proper syntax; I suggest that you study the documentation a little.  Also, the RcppExamples package has something close to what you want to try here.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: Nice going without a comment.  The OP is confused; we wrote eight separate pdf documents plus countless blog and list posts -- I cannot and will not repeat these here. `A(i))(j))(n)` is simply wrong.

Comment: I also replied on list with an example. One perhaps subtle thing here is that rep( 0, m ) creates a *numeric* vector, so when you do as<IntegerVector>, the numeric vector gets turned into an integer vector, which is modified, and then gets discarded. The code "works" if you do as<NumericVector>. I would not write it like that though...